# preRenderView-Event triggered before an action (commandbutton)

Tags: jsf-2

I am in a little bit of trouble with my preRenderView-Event. My page also uses a commandbutton to submit data but unfortunately the preRenderView-Event is always called before the buttons action is invoked.

The preRenderView-Event is responsible for loading data from a service. Since the page is simple and doesnt have to store any data I dont need any Session or ViewScoped-Beans.

As far as I understood the event is called in the Render-Response-Phase and the action in the button should happen somewhat earlier.

```
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" converter="converter.SetOfLongConverter"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.initializeData}" />
    </f:metadata>

    <ui:composition template="/META-INF/templates/myTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="title" value="#{bean.title}"/>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:outputText value="#{bean.description}" />
            <h:form>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Model" for="model" />
                        <h:inputText id="model" value="#{bean.model}" />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Manufacturer" for="manufacturer" />
                        <h:inputText id="manufacturer"
                            value="#{bean.manufacturer}" />
                        <h:outputLabel value="Year" for="year" />
                        <h:inputText id="year" value="#{bean.year}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:commandButton value="Create" type="submit"  action="#{bean.create}" rendered="#{bean.createMode}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Save" type="submit" action="#{bean.save}" rendered="#{!bean.createMode}" />
                </h:form>       
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

I added some Console-Messages to verify when the method in the bean is called and when I have the preRenderView-event it never happens.

Any advice what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<f:metadata>` has to go inside `<ui:define>` of an `<ui:composition>`.

See also [`<f:metadata>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html) (emphasis mine):

> Declare the metadata facet for this view. This must be a child of the `<f:view>`. **This tag must reside within the top level XHTML file for the given viewId, or in a template client, but not in a template.** The implementation must insure that the direct child of the facet is a UIPanel, even if there is only one child of the facet. The implementation must set the id of the UIPanel to be the value of the `UIViewRoot.METADATA_FACET_NAME` symbolic constant.

The simple reason is because the metadata is supposed to be view-specific, not template-specific.

---

**Update**: it turns out that the action method is not invoked at all. You've there a `rendered` attribute on the command button which seems according the symptoms to be dependent on a request based variable instead of a view based variable. Putting the managed bean in the view scope should fix this problem. See also [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but it still doesnt trigger the action. I used the example provided by the link, defining a f:view and a metadata define-section.

Comment: Oh, the bean action method is **not invoked at all**? Your question was not that clear. I understood that it was invoked *after* the listener method, which I guessed to be caused by wrong location of the `<f:metadata>` which may cause undeterministic behaviour. I now see that you've a `rendered` attribute on the button (which escaped my attention because it was outside the viewport). In that case, putting bean in view scope should fix it. See also point 5 of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked

Comment: thats it...thanks. Maybe I can find another solution so I wont need the ViewScope.

Comment: Pass the request based condition where the `rendered` attribute depends on along to the next request by `<f:param>` nested inside `<h:commandButton>`.